# Why didn't Harry like the way Kevin looked at him?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, home-alone

In "Home Alone", after Harry says "Merry Christmas" to Kevin after telling him to look out for Traffic and then Kevin looks a little shocked with his mouth open, why does Harry not like the way he looked at him?

Answer (score 7):

The way I read the scene is when Kevin looked at Harry and noticed his gold tooth, he recognized him as the 'police officer' who had been in their house a few days previous. Harry noticed the look of recognition on Kevin's face and this made him uneasy.

Comment: I would add that, in terms of emotion, the look on Kevin's face was fear. That puts the effectiveness of his disguise into question, thus making Harry nervous.